# Two branches has the same code base by mistake, how to get back?

Tags: git

I have two branches, A and B, B is branched from A, after that:

1. A and B both have changes of there own.
2. Sometimes B got some changes from A(through merge), but B **never** merge back to A, since A and B are parallel projects.

Everything works well until i suddenly found A branch is the same with B(with everything the same). I must run a silly command by mistake, which lead to A lost.

My question is how to get my A branch back? what the command i run by mistake supposed to be?

Many thanks.

Comment: I suggest that we try to establish exactly what happened first, so that we know what we are dealing with! First, double-check that you _are_ actually looking at branch A by typing `git branch` in a command prompt / terminal window and looking for the branch with a `*` next to it. If there is no `*` that would mean you are not on a branch. I recommend not trusting any GUI or tool that runs on top of git when diagnosing weird problems, as such a tool may have bugs.

Comment: Are you using a tool to visualise the changes?  If not, this would be a good idea.  Sourcetree is a good thing to try.  It will show you the flow of changes for both branches, which will help you determine what went wrong.  Once you know what went wrong, then we can try to help fix it....

Comment: Checked, I know this situation is kinds of weird, i have checked it from GUI, git command line, git history and even server side logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must run a silly command by mistake, which lead to A lost.

See what **[`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)** tells you: you should be able to find the previous A HEAD SHA1 in it.
Once you have it:

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard old_A_SHA1
```

(make sure you don't have any private file or work in progress: `reset --hard` resets the working tree)

---

The [OP July](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151513/july) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919445/two-branches-has-the-same-code-base-by-mistake-how-to-get-back/20919967#comment31410167_20919967) the origin of the problem:

> 3 days ago in branch `B`, I run `git push origin A`, and git happily accepted without blame, everything changed since then.

Comment: Problem solved, 3 days ago in branch B i run `git push origin A`, and git happy accepted without blame, everything changed since then. Your suggestion helped. Thanks

Comment: @July Ok. I have included the what you mention in your comment in the answer for more visibility.